# AWS - CloudFormation returned stack-already-exists exception and failed to update to DynamoDB though stack was successfully created

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I want to create my sub-stack (beside my main stack) with AWS SDK, and write the created stack id to DynamoDB. The problem is though the stack was successfully created, the lambda returned `AlreadyExistsException`, and therefore unable to update the stack id to DB. The weird part is that if I removed the `await` before the update DB function, the lambda returned success, but the update function won't proceed. The create sub-stack lambda function is called when my main stack has finished creating, which's status can be retrieved from SNS.

What can I do to achieve my goal?

My code is something like below:

```
public async createMyStack(dataId) {
    let stackId = '';

    let data = this.dbService.getData(dataId);

    if (!data.StackId) {
        const cfn = new AWS.CloudFormation({
            region: 'us-east-1'
        });

        let stackInput: AWS.CloudFormation.Types.CreateStackInput = [
            // Some stack input here
        ];

        // create the stack
        await cfn.createStack(stackInput, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                throw err;
            }
        
            stackId = data.StackId ?? '';
        }).promise();

        // write stack id to DB
        if (stackId) {
            try {
                await this.dbService.update('StackId', stackId);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
                throw error;
            }
        }
    }

    return stackId;
}
```

Comment: whats stack duplicated exception?

Comment: @Lasek To be precise, it's `AlreadyExistsException`. I'll edit the post

Comment: You provided too little information, whats dbservice?

Comment: @Lasek That's my custom service for working with DynamoDB, and it's working fine so far, so no need to concern about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `createStack` is using both promise and callback, therefore the operation get executed twice.
Either using promise or callback **(not both)** get the problem solved.

```
// create the stack
cfn.createStack(stackInput, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        throw err;
    }
        
    stackId = data.StackId ?? '';
});
```

Or

```
// create the stack
try {
    await cfn.createStack(stackInput).promise();
    stackId = data.StackId ?? '';
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw error;
}
```